# How can I flash the NXP S32K148 using J-Link?

Tags: cortex-m, nxp-microcontroller, segger-jlink

I'm working on a S32K148 with VS Code and J-Link. This is part of NXP's S32Kxxx series of 32-bit ARM Cortex M4-based MCUs targeted for high-reliability automobile and industrial applications.

I want to flash the chip using JFlash (with J-Link), but it seems that flashing has been disabled.

My research suggests that I need to have a LinkScript file for the S32Kxxx device, but I cannot find such a file anywhere.

Is my assumption correct that a LinkScript file is needed? If so, where can I find this file?

Comment: Cross-posted on [the NXP forums](https://community.nxp.com/t5/S32K/Where-can-I-download-S32K148-LinkScript-file-for-flash-purpose/m-p/1201553#M9304)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to ensure that the MCU's reset pin is connected to the reset pin of the J-Link. Without this done properly, you will not be able to connect via J-Link.

Next, it must be noted that the design of the S32Kxxx series makes it impossible to attach to a debugging session via J-Link out of the box. The Segger wiki contains a more detailed description:

> **ECC protected internal RAM**
>
> The device series provide ECC protected internal RAM. By default, J-Link resets the MCU on connect and initializes the RAM contents to 0x00. This is done for the following reasons:
>
> - If a memory window in the debugger is open during the debug session and points to a non-initialized RAM region, on the next single step etc. a non-maskable ECC error interrupt would be thrown
> - J-Link temporarily uses some portions of the RAM during flash programming and accesses to non-initialized RAM areas would throw non maskable ECC error interrupts
>
> **Attach to debug session**
>
> For the reasons mentioned [above, in the section "ECC protected internal RAM"], no out of the box attach is possible. This is because there is no way to distinguish between an attach and a connect.
>
> To attach to the device the following [J-Link script file](https://wiki.segger.com/J-Link_script_file) can be used:
>
> - [File:NXP_Kinetis_S32_Attach.JLinkScript](https://wiki.segger.com/File:NXP_Kinetis_S32_Attach.JLinkScript)
>
> **Note:**
> This script file is only supposed to be used in case of an attach, as it skips the device specific connect.

So, your research is correct: in order to attach to the device, you must use a J-Link script, which can be downloaded [here from Segger](https://wiki.segger.com/File:NXP_Kinetis_S32_Attach.JLinkScript). The contents are reprinted below:

```
*               (c) SEGGER Microcontroller GmbH & Co. KG             *
*                        The Embedded Experts                        *
*                           www.segger.com                           *
**********************************************************************

-------------------------- END-OF-HEADER -----------------------------

File    : NXP_Kinetis_S32_Attach.JLinkScript
Purpose : Script file to skip the device specific connect for the
          NXP Kinetis S32 devices, to make an attach possible.
Literature:
  [1]  J-Link User Guide
*/

/*********************************************************************
*
*       Constants (similar to defines)
*
**********************************************************************
*/

/*********************************************************************
*
*       Global variables
*
**********************************************************************
*/

/*********************************************************************
*
*       Local functions
*
**********************************************************************
*/

/*********************************************************************
*
*       Global functions
*
**********************************************************************
*/

/*********************************************************************
*
*       InitTarget()
*
*  Function description
*    If present, called right before performing generic connect sequence.
*    Usually used for targets which need a special connect sequence.
*    E.g.: TI devices with ICEPick TAP on them where core TAP needs to be enabled via specific ICEPick sequences first
*
*  Return value
*    >= 0:  O.K.
*     < 0:  Error
*
*  Notes
*    (1) Must not use high-level API functions like JLINK_MEM_ etc.
*    (2) For target interface JTAG, this device has to setup the JTAG chain + JTAG TAP Ids.
*/
int InitTarget(void) {
  //
  // As this script file is only used for attach purposes, no special handling is required.
  // Therefore, we override the default connect handled by the J-Link DLL for this device.
  // as it would trigger a reset.
  //
  return 0;
}

/*************************** end of file ****************************/
```

Comment: Thank @Cody Gray, I realize that my question was a very very stupid question. I cannot flash chip by JFlash just because I choose default project setting and the defaut project use Cortex-M0 as device, So that why JFlash cannot flash S32K (Cortex-M4).